# Does WindowsIdentity constructor need network connection for local user actions?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get information about the currently logged in user via a Windows service, specifically is the user is an admin level role or not. The service is properly collecting the currently logged in user, and I have code that works when the computer the service is running on is connected to the network, but I can't always guarantee the computer will be on the network when the service does this user level check.

Long story short, does WindowsIdentity require the computer be connected to the network to create an identity? I can't find anything online that clearly states if this is the case.

I only need to get whether or not the current user is an admin level role or not for the local system. I don't care if it's an admin at the domain level, although I understand this is probably going to be the case if the system is on a network.
If there is a better way to do this for my needs, I am happy to see other recommendations.

I have done some major googling and looked at a number of other SO answers, but none of them seem to work when the computer is not on the network. They did help me get a version that works when the computer is on the network though.

I also looked at the MS documentation for this and don't see anything clear about network needs. I may have missed something thought.

The below method works while on network.

```
    private bool IsUserAdministrator(string accountName)
    {
        var result = false;

        try
        {
            using (var identity = new WindowsIdentity(accountName))
            {
                var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
                var adminSid = new SecurityIdentifier("BA");
                result = principal.UserClaims.Any(c => c.Value.Equals(adminSid.ToString()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Exception handled by returning false
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This method also works, when on network. The failure point while debugging is the new WindowsIdentity().

```
    private bool IsUserAdministrator(string accountName)
    {
        using (WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(accountName))
        {
            WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
            return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }
    }
```

Once again, when connected to the network, both of these either return 'true' when the user is an admin role, or 'false' when the user is not admin role.

When not connected to the network this fails and throws the exception {"There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.\r\n"}.

Is this an issue with WindowsIdentity or is something else causing this? Is this an LDAP issue?

Sorry, I realize there are multiple questions spread throughout this, but the number one issue is, does WindowsIdentity need network connection, and if yes, is there another way to achieve my goals?

Comment: From my understanding, WindowsIdentity requires a network connection. I do not believe there is another way to do this.

Comment: @Aiyuni - Thanks for the response! My testing seems to back this up. I will just handle the exception and refactor my code to handle situations where there is no network connection and the user role level is unknown. It's not optimal, but I think we can change our requirements to make this an acceptable solution.